# How to delete a specific item form json data by usnig a button in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

### How to delete a specific item from JSON using javascript

A mainly I want to delete Mon -> from time to be empty after clicking a button

```
const arr = {
    "Mon": [
        {
          "from": "08:00 AM",
          "to": "09:00 AM"
        },
        {
          "from": "06:00 PM",
          "to": "07:00 PM"
        }
      ],

    "Sun": [
        {
        "from": "",
        "to": ""
        },
        {
        "from": "",
        "to": ""
        }
    ]
};
```

```js
const arr = {

    "Mon": [
        {
          "from": "08:00 AM",
          "to": "09:00 AM"
        },
        {
          "from": "06:00 PM",
          "to": "07:00 PM"
        }
      ],
      
    "Sun": [
        {
        "from": "",
        "to": ""
        },
        {
        "from": "",
        "to": ""
        }
    ]
};
```

it is not working please help me

Comment: Output is same as input

Comment: What have you tried? And what is your expected output?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal,*A mainly I want to delete Mon*

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut OP says ` delete Mon -> from time` which means delete Mon? or delete Mon->from time? or both the from time from Mon? or first from time from Mon?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut It does not suit you to answer such incomplete question

Comment: Then question must be closed as "unclear what asking"

Answer (score 0):

I am a slight novice to Javascript but I think you are using const which should be var. Then you can completely remove object through delete as mentioned below:

```
 delete arr.Mon.from;
```

or to make it empty you can use

```
  arr.Mon.from = new Date();
```

or to make it null you can use

```
arr.Mon.from = null;
```